# Still Trying to Grasp Deferreds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am tasked with creating a printable corporate directory from records kept in a Sharepoint 2013 custom list. As with other pages in the site, I am accessing the list's contents via the REST functionality.

There are more than 100 records in the list and there is a 99 item limit on SharePoint REST which I am trying to bypass by querying the list for all A-M and then N-Z and then using jquery's extend or merge to combine the objects.

Since I have to account for the asynchronous traps of AJAX, I am trying to use a Deferred and I thought I had finally grasped that but NO ...

here is my jquery:

```
var printme = {
    init: function(){
        $('.ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin').css('display', 'none');
        $('#contentBox').css('margin-left', '0' );
        $('#pageTitle').html("Corporate Directory -- Printable");

        var firstHalf = this.getFirstHalf();
        console.log(firstHalf);
    },
    getFirstHalf: function(){
        var dfd = new $.Deferred();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/humanresources/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Corporate Directory')/items?$filter=Title ge 'a' and Title lt 'n'&?orderby=Title asc",
            type: "GET",
            headers: { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: dfd.resolve
        });

        return dfd.promise();
    }
};
$(document).ready( function(){
    printme.init();
});
```

The console log DOES NOT contain the expected 43 records but instead length is 1. I plan on making a call to a future function (getSecondHalf) and then merge the 2 responses and pass it to a Handlebars template for processing. This is the console.log:

```
Object {state: function, always: function, then: function, promise: function, pipe: function…}
always: function () {
done: function () {
fail: function () {
pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
progress: function () {
promise: function ( obj ) {
arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them]
get arguments: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }
set arguments: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }
caller: (...)
get caller: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }
set caller: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }
length: 1
name: ""
prototype: Object
__proto__: function Empty() {}
<function scope>
state: function () {
then: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
__proto__: Object
```

-UPDATE-
Here is my jquery now:

```
var printme = {
    init: function(){
        $('.ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin').css('display', 'none');
        $('#contentBox').css('margin-left', '0' );
        $('#pageTitle').html("Corporate Directory -- Printable");

        var firstHalfDeferred = $.ajax({ 
            url: "/humanresources/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Corporate Directory')/items?$filter=Title ge 'a' and Title lt 'n'&?orderby=Title asc",
            type: "GET",
            headers: { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
        var secondHalfDeferred = $.ajax({
            url: "/humanresources/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Corporate Directory')/items?$filter=Title ge 'n' and Title lt 'z'&?orderby=Title asc",
            type: "GET",
            headers: { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            dataType: 'json'
        });

        $.when(firstHalfDeferred, secondHalfDeferred).done(function(firstHalf, secondHalf) {
            var result = $.extend({}, firstHalf[0], secondHalf[0]);

            Handlebars.registerHelper("formatPhone", function(Phone){
                phone = Phone.toString();
                return phone.substr(0,3) + '.' + phone.substr(3,3) + '.' + phone.substr(6,4);
            });

            var pcd_tmpl = $("#tmpl-corporate_print").html();
            var pcd_template = Handlebars.compile(pcd_tmpl);
            $('#print_pane').append( pcd_template(result) );

        }).fail(function(errorData) {
             console.log('Error: ' + errorType + ' with message: ' + errorMessage);
        });
    },
};

$(document).ready( function(){
    printme.init();
});
```

And my Handlebars template is:

```
<div id="print_pane" style="float:left; width: 100%; padding:0 10px 0 40px;">
    <script id="tmpl-corporate_print" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <table cellpadding='5' cellspacing='10'>
        {{#each this}}
            <tr style="padding:10px;">
                <td style="width:120px;text-align:center;">
                <img alt="{{ Full_x0020_Name }}" src="/humanresources/CorporateFaces/{{ ImgName }}.png" />
                </td>
            <td>
                    <h1>{{ Full_x0020_Name }}</h1>
                    <h2>{{ JobTitle }}</h2>
                <h2>{{ Department }}</h2>
                <h3><b>{{formatPhone Phone}}</b></h3>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
</script>
</div>
```

It is throwing the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined

Is that because I don't know how to access the data elements because Phone (which is definitely in the list) is returning null.

Here is a single return value:

```
Object {d: Object}
d: Object
results: Array[53]
0: Object
AttachmentFiles: Object
Attachments: false
AuthorId: 2
Birthday: "11/21"
ContentType: Object
ContentTypeId: "0x0100533BA85B2C40D04B9578F78D81D2D12C"
CopyMana: null
CopyMana0: 5
Created: "2014-02-21T17:38:06Z"
Department: "Management Services (MSD)"
EditorId: 2
Email: "cripas@corporate.com"
Extension: "52587"
FieldValuesAsHtml: Object
FieldValuesAsText: Object
FieldValuesForEdit: Object
File: Object
FileSystemObjectType: 0
FirstName: "Christine"
FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject: Object
Folder: Object
Full_x0020_Name: "Christine Ripas"
GUID: "cdd3326b-fc1e-40f2-a070-aa00fb0c6598"
ID: 6
Id: 6
Img: Object
JobTitle: "Senior Vice President & COO"
MFN: "Randy Chairman"
ManagerId: 1
Modified: "2014-02-26T19:42:20Z"
OData__UIVersionString: "1.0"
ParentList: Object
Phone: "9015556767"
RoleAssignments: Object
Title: "Ripas"
__metadata: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Well of course it doesn't contain anything, it hasn't finished executing yet. You need to attach a `done` function which gets called when your deferred is done. BTW: since $.ajax returns a deferred, you don't need to create one.

Comment: Deferreds do not make asynchronous code behave synchronously. You still need callbacks. However, Promises are an abstraction to compose the callbacks very easily.

Comment: Instead of writing `$(document).ready(function () { ... })` you can simply pass the function directly to jQuery: `$(function () {...})` – it's a shorthand.

Comment: Where do I attach the done function? in the init or in the getFirstHalf?

Comment: `firstHalf` is a jqXHR (well, in this case it's actually a promise, but you should change `getFirstHalf` to have it directly return `$.ajax(...)`,) to get the data, you'll have to add a callback to it's done method.

Comment: I removed the getFirstHalf method based on the answers below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is redundant as $.ajax already returns a promise (subset of deferred). You can do something like this:

```
var firstHalfDeferred = $.ajax({ /* settings for first half */});
var secondHalfDeferred = $.ajax({ /* settings for second half */});

$.when(firstHalfDeferred, secondHalfDeferred).done(function(firstHalf, secondHalf) {
   var result = $.extend({}, firstHalf[0], secondHalf[0]);

}).fail(function(errorData) {
   //take care of errors.
});
```

First, you get two promises. Then, the $.when() function waits for both (for any number you pass to it, actually) to complete, or for any of them to throw an error. The done() method will take a function that will receive as many arguments as deferreds you passed to $.when. Each of those arguments is an array with the three objects jQuery pass to an AJAX success handler, so arg[0] is the data. You only have to mix the two objects received (this because you said so, I don't know which kind of data does Sharepoint return).

If anything fails, the argument to the fail() method is executed.

Comment: Notice that `$.ajax` does not return a *Deferred*, but a *Promise*

Comment: I fixed my code according to the suggestions and added it to my question in the update. I am getting an error because I am not sure how to access a single element (that I know is in the return object). I put that in the question as well.  THANKS GREATLY for the help!!!

Comment: another thing I noticed is that firstHalfDeferred is returning 75 list rows and secondHalfDeferred is returning 53 list rows. However, when we merge the two, result only has 53 array items instead of the 128 items I would expect and which I need.

Comment: Maybe $.extend() is not the best way to combine the results. For what I see, the actual results come in the property 'result', not the object itself. $.extend() will replace one array with the other. Try `var results = firstHalf[0].results.concat(secondHalf[0].results);`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `$.ajax` returns a promise in itself, so there's no need to create one manually. You can simply `return $.ajax`.

However, the problem is that the object you are inspecting is the promise itself. When the promise is resolved, the value is passed to the function inside a `.then()` or `.done()` that you've attached to it.

So you want:

```
firstHalf.done(function (value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```